# why my redux custom middleware need to return dispatch on action?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'd set redux custom middleware, and change on action to insert argument  on action. But the result is `actions must be plain objects. use custom middleware for async actions` because in action i did't `return dispatch(myAction)`

my configure middleware

```
const injectMiddleware = ({dispatch, getState}) => next => action => {

//skipped all my logic

return(
  typeof action === 'function' ?
    next(action({dispatch, getState, ...anotherCustomFunction}))
    :
    next(action)
)
}
```

my Actions

```
export const setUserSessionToken = () => ({dispatch}: Store) => {
  dispatch(setToken)
}
```

and get Error
`actions must be plain objects. use custom middleware for async actions`

fixed with `return`

```
export const setUserSessionToken = () => ({dispatch}: Store) => {
  return dispatch(setToken)
}
```

and `no error` without `return` if not using custom middleware

```
export const setUserSessionToken = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setToken)
}
```

or in custom middleware just do

```
return next(action)
```

Comment: what is the value of setToken? dispatch is a method that wants an object as parameter. 
ex.
`{type: YOUR_TYPE", data: "yourData"}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change this

`next(action({dispatch, getState, ...anotherCustomFunction}))`

as

`action({dispatch, getState, ...anotherCustomFunction})`

calling next is passing an action object to the next middleware. Of course, you can pass a function that not evaluated yet, but you will need another middleware like thunk to handle the function eventually.